# Display HTML value in form id html-editor-form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Four Sections. Each Section gets displayed when I click the respective icon.

The `visual-editor` section has lot of html values.

I want to display all html values under class `visual-editor` in `html-editor` section.

I have a text area field I want to put all html element under `visual-editor` class as value.

```html
<div class="editor-container">
  <div class="visual-editor">

    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Pricing</h1>
      <p class="lead">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It’s built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Priority email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>30 users included</li>
              <li>15 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Phone and email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Pricing</h1>
      <p class="lead">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It’s built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Priority email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>30 users included</li>
              <li>15 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Phone and email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="html-editor">
    <textarea id="html-editor-form" class="form-control" rows="5">
    
   </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="css-editor">
    <p>css editor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="js-editor">
    <p>js editor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `html value`? Does it mean the whole html code or just the text in between tags?If I understood your question fully, you want the html inside of `visual-editor` to be displayed in `html-editor` 's `textarea` element. Correct?

Comment: Whole html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `innerHTML` to get html of `.visual-editor` and the assign this content to the `textarea`.

```js
const visualEditor = document.querySelector('.visual-editor');

document.querySelector('.html-editor textarea').value = visualEditor.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="editor-container">
  <div class="visual-editor">

    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Pricing</h1>
      <p class="lead">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It’s built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Priority email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>30 users included</li>
              <li>15 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Phone and email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Pricing</h1>
      <p class="lead">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It’s built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Priority email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>30 users included</li>
              <li>15 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Phone and email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="html-editor">
    <textarea id="html-editor-form" class="form-control" rows="5">
              
          </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="css-editor">
    <p>css editor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="js-editor">
    <p>js editor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```